# django user authenticate only returns None

Tags: python, django

i'm trying to create a simple API on Django, and this is my first. The class User get the AbstractUser,  like this:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class Usuario(AbstractUser):
    nome = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=150, unique=True, blank=False, null=False, default="")
    nascimento = models.DateField()
    password = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=False, null=False, default="")
```

But when I try to authenticate, the method allways returns None. Why?
I checked, on DataBase, and the Users are already there.

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from conta.models import Usuario
import secrets
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login

def login_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        user = request.POST.get("user")
        senha = request.POST.get("password")
        autenticador = authenticate(request, username=user, password=senha)
        if autenticador is None:
            context = {"error" : "Invalid username or password"}
            return render(request, "conta/tela_de_login.html", context)
        login(request, autenticador)
        redirect('/admin')
    return render(request, "conta/tela_de_login.html", {})
```

Answer (score 0):

You are likely comparing user object with username, which is string. Try this:

```
autenticador = authenticate(request, username=user.username, password=senha)
```

Comment: I don't think thats the case since he is using a form to retrieve the username (user) and password (senha) so it should be strings already.

Answer (score 0):

Chack this is :-

```
def login_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(request, username = username, password = password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            messages.success(request, f' wellcome {username} !!')
            return redirect('admin')
        else:
            messages.warning(request, f'Invalid username or password')
    return render(request, "conta/tela_de_login.html", {})
```

But i don't understand why you redirect "admin page after login.

Comment: This is just a test, and will redirect to another page.

Comment: oooo... chack new